# Dropdown Category Product Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

i am working on a project about a restaurant.In the wine section i have  listed all the wines and i have done a dropdown list that shows all the categories of wines from my database and that is ok, i need to do another value on dropdown that shows me again all the wines after i have selected 1 category.
Thanks in advance.

This is my Controller

```
 public function index()
{
    $wines = Wines::where('visible','yes')->where('delete','no')->get();
    $wines_categories = Wines_Categories::where('visible','yes')->where('delete','no')->get();

    return view('wines.wines', ['wines' => $wines,'wines_categories' => $wines_categories]);
}


/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index_filtered(Request $request)
{

    if(isset($request->category))
    {
        $wines = Wines::where('visible','yes')->where('delete','no')->where('id_wine_category',$request->category)->get();
    }
    else
    {
        $wines = Wines::where('visible','yes')->where('delete','no')->get();
    }
    $wines_categories = Wines_Categories::where('visible','yes')->where('delete','no')->get();
    return view('wines.wines', ['wines' => $wines,'wines_categories' => $wines_categories]);
}
```

This is my dropdown section

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'wines_filtered','role' => 'form', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')) !!}

                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-2 pull-right"style="margin-top: 50px">
                            <div class="select-style input-round med-input shop-shorting-full">
                                <select name="category" onchange="this.form.submit()"style="font-weight: bold; color: #ac2d24;text-align: center">

                                    <option value="" > Scegli Categoria </option>

                                    @foreach($wines_categories as $wines_category)

                                        <option value="{{$wines_category->id}}">{{$wines_category->name}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: You said what you need, you failed to say what the problem is.

Comment: Your question doesn't clear what you require.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this @ Controller :**

```
public function index(){
$wines_categories = Wines::pluck('name', 'id')->where('visible','yes')->where('delete','no')->get(); 
}
```

**at your form**

```
{!! Form::select('category_id', $wines_categories , null,['placeholder' => 'Select categories...', 'required' => 'required'])!!}
```

**Foreach Not required for the laravel blade dropdown option**. If you give an array of categories then it will auto show on the list.

Let me know if u have any problem.

Comment: that shows me everythinfg from the DB, i have already take the category, i just need and option to thow again all the wines after i have selected one category.